# How do I tweak a responsive table’s JavaScript to select a different column in mobile

Tags: javascript

Here is my CodePen:

https://codepen.io/matbathome77/pen/KeEzZG

```
var pos = $(this).index()+2;
```

It is based on someone else’s CodePen. How do I, in the mobile version, have it default to the “1 year” column, and show the content in that column.

Right now it is defaulted to 3 year and it isn’t showing any content under that th until you select the item.

I tried editing the JS on line 4 to be +1 instead of +2, in hopes that this would change the default to 1 year. It didn’t work.

Comment: Ok, I almost have it. However, in mobile view, it's calling the wrong column until you press one of the buttons. The desktop view is correct:

https://codepen.io/matbathome77/pen/KeEzZG

Answer (score 0):

Activate the column on the page load, and also on click. Move the onclick inline function to its own name, then call to it (with the li style updating) when it's clicked on.

from:

```
$( "ul" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index()+2;
  $("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','table-cell');
  $("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

to

```
function loadColumn(pos) {
  $("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','table-cell');
  $("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
}

loadColumn(2);

$( "ul" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index() + 1;
  loadColumn(pos);
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

is what you're looking for.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeEXzR

Comment: It's almost there. I noticed that the wrong column below is being called in mobile. So, when you go to mobile, it should have "1 Year" highlighted, but then the content should also be the "1 year" content. Right now, it seems that when it's mobile, it is putting the content for "Duration" under "1 Year".

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I had to create an li and hide it. I had to also tell the javascript to call the third column, not the second. Thanks all.

https://codepen.io/matbathome77/pen/KeEzZG

```
<li class="hidden">Name (ticker)<br>Bla bla bla category</li>
```

and the css

```
li.hidden {display:none;}
```

finally, the javascript

```
loadColumn(3);
```